# TabPy - No return value

Tags: python, data-visualization, tableau-api, tabpy

I am working in TabPy inside Tableau and want to perform normal statistical calculations.

I am stuck with Cp calculation. Here is the code that I wrote -

```
    SCRIPT_REAL("

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats


# Calculate Cp

def Cp(list,_arg2,_arg3):
   arr = np.array(list)
   arr = arr.ravel()
   sigma = np.std(arr)
   Cp = float(_arg2 - _arg3) / (6*sigma)
   return Cp


",FLOAT([USL - Param]), FLOAT([LSL - Param]))
```

The error that I am getting is -

**No Return Value**

although I am clearly returning Cp. What could be the issue?

Please help.

Comment: You're just defining the `Cp` function, you aren't calling it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below would solve some of the issues you're seeing.

I haven't checked the validity of your Cp function, and whether this would work with lists or single values.

```
SCRIPT_REAL("

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats


# Define Cp

def Cp(argu_1,argu_2):
   arr = np.array(list)
   arr = arr.ravel()
   sigma = np.std(arr)
   Cp_value = float(argu_1 - argu_2) / (6*sigma)
   return Cp_value

# Call function with variables from Tableau, and return the Cp_value
return Cp(<Argument 1>, <Argument 2>)

",FLOAT([USL - Param]), FLOAT([LSL - Param]))
```